# How to auto submit a form using JavaScript and JSP?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, cookies

I have a JSP web application, i use JavaScript to read a value from a saved cookie, let's say it is a login page and if i found the user name and password in the cookie will automatically add the values in the user name and password in their relative HTML input fields so far i can do this easily, however i need to automatically submit the form without clicking on the submit button, how can i fire this click event wither using JavaScript or JSP?

Note: because of very specific business need and using of third party code and architecture i have to implement the scenario as i described, unfortunately can't use servlets or redirect to other pages

am using the following code, which does not work :(

```
    <%!

//JSP code to validate the cookie and get the values
 if(true)
  {
   %>
   <!-- JavaScript code -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
         document.forms["myForm"]["buttonSubmit"].click();
     </script>
  <%!
  }
  %>
```

Comment: why aren't you just triggering the submit of the form itself? Also put code in a page load event handler if script precedes the form elements so form exists when code is run

Comment: Thank you very much  charlietfl , you are correct
i did so and worked

Comment: I tried to trigger the form submit event but never worked with me even though i referenced the form by name and by id

Comment: any errors in browser console? Seems like you could just make an ajax call for this also. Purpose is not clear at all